# Administrator of this Mac Disabled Your User Account from Accessing USB Network Gate

Tags: applications

When I try to install the application "USB Network Gate" I get message "Administrator of this Mac Disabled Your User Account from Accessing USB Network Gate. If your require further assistance, please contact your local/network administrator."

[image]

I'm logged in as user "admin" and "Allow user to administer this computer" is checked in my account.

I'm trying to install the app from a downloaded .dmg file. I've had no issues installing other applications.

How can I install this application?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a custom message from the vendor, not from macOS. It’s probably incorrect. I suspect it is trying to load an invalid kernel extension and failing. Ask the vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki available on the [official web-site](https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/), current user should be a member of the "staff" group to get rid of the "Administrator of this Mac disabled your user account..." message.

Check whether the user is a member of the "staff" group:

```
dscl . -read /groups/staff | grep GroupMembership
```

If not, add the user to the "staff" group":

```
sudo dscl . -append /groups/staff GroupMembership <user>
```

where <*user*> is the user's numeric ID or account name.

Hope this will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are an admin on this Mac it *may* be that your app security settings need to be either relaxed or for you to give that app permission to install.

Go to System Preferences > Security > General and click on the lock icon and authenticate. That app might be listed for you to explicitly give it permission to run. If not make sure that "Allow Apps downloaded from: app store and identified developers" is selected.

You might also want to ask the developer if they have seen this behavior and what their specific solution is.

Comment: I've clicked the lock and authenticated and now the lock icon shows as open. Allow apps downloaded from = Anywhere (which seems to be a more relaxed security option for this issue). Should I see the app listed (to give it permission to run here? I've added an additional screenshot of the security privacy settings window to the question.

Comment: You may want to ask the developer, your settings seem to be correct

Answer (score 0):

MacinCloud support provided a solution. After running this in the terminal I was able to successfully install the USB Network Gate application.

> sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a admin -t user staff